# Offer to send me 5000 and then send 4000 to his daughter. I think this is a scam. Is it?

Tags: united-states, scams

My question is to find out if I'm being scammed.

This guy  says he's from California (area code 909) and we met at an online dating site. Says he has a daughter in TX, 30 yr old.

He is asking if he could do a "wire transfer" to my account from his account; attaching my account to his checking account.

He says he's going to transfer 5000 to my account. I'm to keep a thousand and send his daughter the rest by account transfer. I should also buy a few things for her and send them to her.

I'm feeling like this is a scam as he asked me for my online bank account user ID and password and security code.

He says he is on a boat for some kind of training and won't be back for 12 days. This was 2 weeks ago and I was like then your daughter can wait 'till you get back.

So is this a scam?  It's smelling like one.  I keep saying to just use my routing number and account number but he says it has be done with my user id, password, and security code.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, it is a scam. The $5000 deposit to your account will bounce and you will be out whatever you sent. Also, no one should ask for your password.

Comment: Except in this scenario, I don't think there will even be the initial transfer since the scammer is asking for username / password to the OP's account. The scammer will just drain the account

Answer (score 19):

That has got to be one of the scammiest scams that has ever scammed.  Do not continue interacting with this person unless you really, really want to get ripped off.

You need to stop and ask yourself a few questions:

1. Why would he (or anyone) possibly need you to relay money like this for anything even remotely legitimate?
2. Why would they pay you $1000 for something that (even if it weren't a scam) represents a fairly trivial amount of work on your part?
3. Why would they need your banking login info?

The answer to all three of these is **they wouldn't**.
No one who isn't either a scammer or otherwise *seriously* sketchy is going to ask someone that they met over the internet and barely know to transfer money for them.  And they certainly aren't going to pay them $1000 for less than an hour's work.  And they really, really aren't going to ask for your login info.

Banking is deliberately designed so that people can make payments and purchases without revealing that information.  If they're given that info, then they aren't setting something up *for* you, they *are* you.  You might eventually get your account back, but likely not before it's been drained of everything they can get their hands on.  Even if that didn't happen, the money you'd receive stands an excellent chance of being stolen or procured through criminal activity.  Meaning that you could have the police paying you a visit for your role in laundering money.

The *best case scenario* for this is that you receive $5k, send off $4k, and then find that the initial deposit has been reversed, leaving you "only" $4k in the hole.  That's if you're very, very lucky.

As pretty much every bank will tell you, don't give out your login info.  Don't give it to your friends, don't give it to your family, don't give it to someone claiming to be a bank employee, don't give it to anyone, period.

Comment: The _biggest_ red flag is: he can't send the money direct to his daughter because he's on a boat... but he _can_ wire you the money...

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it's a scam. If he can wire money to your account, he can wire money to his daughter's account. Besides, wire transfers don't need your login name or password, as you rightly noted.

This is a [phishing scam](https://www.scamwatch.gov.au/types-of-scams/attempts-to-gain-your-personal-information/phishing) dressed up as a [romance scam](https://www.scamwatch.gov.au/types-of-scams/dating-romance), presenting as a kind of [unexpected-money scam](https://www.scamwatch.gov.au/types-of-scams/unexpected-money).

Answer (score 5):

This is a scam. After getting the user ID and password, he will clean up your account or use it for illegal activities.

There is no money for you. Don't share your account number.